# How to pass multiple elements in dictionary to replace values python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pass a full array into a dictionary as keys and get the values out:

```
dic = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
lista = [1,2,3]

dic.get(1)
'a'

dic.get(list)
error
```

thanks

Comment: I know i cant use list as a variable, please pretend its lista (I also know its an array)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) here.

```
from operator import itemgetter

dic = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
lst = [1, 2, 3]
itemgetter(*lst)(dic)
# ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: This seems faster than mine... thanks for this!

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Thank you. I did not timeit but good to know :)

Answer (score 3):

Use -

```
dic = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
list_ = [1,2,3]

a = [dic.get(k) for k in list_]
```

**@Ch3steR**

```
453 ns ± 192 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

**-->thisone**

```
888 ns ± 430 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

in pandas its called the map function:

```
lista = lista.map(dic)
```

cheers

Comment: Is `lista` Series object?

Answer (score 0):

We can do `map`

```
[*map(dic.get,lista)]
Out[270]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```